# How to find out if an object is touching another object in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

(excuse my bad english, I am 13 years old)
alright, even though i just joined stackoverflow today, I have been coding for a while. I'm trying to make a simple game (and may make it something bigger later) and I want the hammer (the player sprite) not be able to go through the box toward the middle of the screen, but I don't know how. here is what I have:

```js
var sq = document.getElementById("box"); 
  var posX = 0;
  var posY = 0;
  var rot = "rotate(0deg)";
var id = null;
  function move(object, pixels, xa){          
    if(xa == true) {
      posX+=pixels;
      object.style.left = posX + 'px'; 
    }else{
      posY+=pixels;
      object.style.top = posY + 'px'; 
    }
  }
   OBJect.style.left = "200px"; 
  OBJect.style.top = "200px"; 
document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);
    function logKey(e) {
      if (`${e.code}` == "ArrowRight") {
        rot = "rotate(90deg)";
         sq.style.transform = rot;
     move(sq, 5, true);
                     if(posX > 470){
        posX = 5;
      }
      }
          if (`${e.code}` == "ArrowLeft") {
            rot = "rotate(270deg)";
            sq.style.transform = rot;
                    move(sq, -5, true);
                         if(posX < 0){
        posX = 465;
      }
      }
          if (`${e.code}` == "ArrowDown") {
            rot = "rotate(180deg)";
            sq.style.transform = rot;
         move(sq, 5, false);
                  if(posY > 465){
        posY = 5;
      }
      }
          if (`${e.code}` == "ArrowUp") {
            rot = "rotate(0deg)";
            sq.style.transform = rot;
        move(sq, -5, false);
                  if(posY < 0){
        posY = 470;
      }
      }
    }
setInterval(function(){
         xaxis.innerHTML = "x: " + posX;
      yaxis.innerHTML = "y: " + posY;
  rotate.innerHTML = rot;
},1);
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
 outline: red solid 10px;
}
#box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
#OBJect {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<style>
/*style would go here/*
</style>
<body>
<div id="myContainer">
<img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/7f9c2ae2-9b45-42a1-a387-380de7f5d3bd%2Fhammer.png?v=1615308683807" alt="hammer" id="box">
  <div id="OBJect"></div>
</div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="xaxis"></div>
  <div id="yaxis"></div>
  <div id="rotate"></div>
<script>
  //script would go here
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

yeah, yeah, I know. I could *definetly* improve, but I only know basic things,and some of these from either Stackoverflow or w3schools, and yes, I know there is a lot of solved answers with this problem, but I get confused by them because they are too complicated for me. I just request easy, simple code to understand (if it isn't, please label things so I know).

**sorry if this is too much, I just need help :/**

Comment: use the [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for both the elements and use a custom logic to find if the `x` or `y` of the second or first is covering over the `x + width` or `y + height`

Answer (score 0):

so to do this you need to know the 4 corners of each element then you need to check if the other object is within the players bounds

they're both rectangles and to be touching 1 of these statements have to be true

1. the top left corner of the square is to the right of the top left corner of the player and the top left corner of the square is to the left of the top right corner of the player while the top left corner of the square is less than the y of the top side and higher than the y of the bottom side
2. the top right corner of the square is to the left of the top right corner of the player and the top right corner of the square is to the right of the top left corner of the player while the top right corner of the square is less than the y of the top side and higher than the y of the bottom side
3. same as 1 & 2 but with the bottom left and right corners
4. if one of the corners has the same x and y as a corner on the other object or if the position of one object is the same as the other

a second way to do this is using Pythagoras theorem to get the distance between two points

a^2 + b^2 = c^2

how that would look in code

```js
let c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(x2, y2), 2))
```

this is a little tricky but the distance between two points is a triangle in a sense so the distance on x and y form the two legs then to get the actual distance we need the hypotenuse which is what Pythagoras theorem gets us. So to get a and b we need to get the absolute value of the first minus second x and y to get the distance on x and y then we square them with `Math.pow()` and add them but that gives us c^2 and we just want c so we get the square root with `Math.sqrt()` which gives us the distance then the one other thing we have to do is get the center of the objects to use as a and b. Since you're working with javascript on a webpage the X and Y values are for the top left corner so you need to add half the width and height to x and y appropriately to get the center of the object, then you can use the distance formula. the only problem with this approach is that it works best for circles because every point around the edge is equally distant from the center which isn't true for a square.

So personally I would use the first method, you can get the other corners by using width and height to add to the position of the top left corner to get the other positions. it's more code but more precise than distance because you're checking the bounds of each object rather than checking distance from center

Answer (score 0):

I also joined today and I am 12. since the hammer is an img, you can use css:

I think your question was that you want to move the hammer, if yes:

```js
var left = 0; /*left and top can be edited in your code but*/
var top = 0;/*you have to reset them using the code below*/
var hammer = document.querySelector('#hammer');
hammer.style.left = left + 'px';
hammer.style.top = top + 'px';
```

```css
#hammer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}/*set left and right via js*/
```

```html
<!--just add an id like #hammer to the hammer-->
```